# How to move MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE from a machine to other machine?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, always-encrypted, certificate-store

I am using the SQL Server "Always Encrypted" feature.

I open SSMS from my local machine, create a column master key (MyCMK1), then create a column encryption key (MyCEK1).

On SSMS, I use the MyCEK1 to encrypt the `SSN` column in the `User` table. Good.

I create a .NET console app + ADO.NET to test the SQL Server "Always Encrypted" feature (`Column Encryption Setting=Enabled;` added into the database connection string).

The result is good, I got an unencrypted `SSN` from ADO.NET result.

Next, I move my console app (`MyConsoleApp.exe`) to other machine, then run the app -> ERROR:

> Failed to decrypt column 'SSN'. Failed to decrypt a column encryption key using key store provider: 'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE'. The last 10 bytes of the encrypted column encryption key are:
> '3B-60-3A-40-AF-16-22-6F-ED-DE'. Certificate with thumbprint
> '93DE41DC5F46FE6FF1436829B9362A508BB3E920' not found in certificate store 'My' in certificate location 'CurrentUser'. Verify the certificate path in the column master key definition in the database is correct, and the certificate has been imported correctly into the certificate location/store. Parameter name: masterKeyPath

The error makes sense since I use `MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE` store type and the app works on my local machine because there is a certificate store file to store the master key at the below location:

```
CurrentUser/my/93DE41DC5F46FE6FF1436829B9362A508BB3E920
```

OR

```
file:\\%APPDATA%\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates\93DE41DC5F46FE6FF1436829B9362A508BB3E920
```

**My question is**: how can I move the certificate store file that stores the master key from my local machine to the other machine?

**Notes:** I open CertMgr on my local machine / Personal / Certificates -> Empty.

Answer (score 1):

This can all be done utilizing your Certificate Manager.

Firstly, on the machine with the certificate you want to export, load up your Certificate Manager (certmgr). Locate your Always Encrypted certificate under Personal -> Certificates, right click on it, and click export. This will open up an Export Wizard which should be pretty self-explanatory.

Next, on the machine you wish to import your certificate on, again load up the Certificate Manager, navigate to Personal -> Certificates, right click in the empty space, and click import. Again, this will open up a wizard which should be pretty self explanatory.

Once you've done these two steps, it should work again.

Comment: Please see my notes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the your Certificate Manager. Use the search certificate by key in your **KeyIdentifier** "93DE41DC5F46FE6FF1436829B9362A508BB3E920" to find your certificate. Then, you can export the certificate and import this exported certificate to your client machine.
[image]

If you double click the certificate, on the details, you will see this **KeyIdentifier** is the thumbprint.

[image]